# Method not working properly

Tags: java

This is a method that i made for my comp sci class:

```
public Time (int y, int x)
{
minute = x;
hour = y;
if (minute>59 || minute<0)
{
 minute = 0; 
}
if (hour>=24 || hour<0)
{
 hour=0; 
}
}

void addOne()
{//Adds one to the minute.  Still in military time
minute++;
 if (minute == 60) //Makes minute never exceeds 59 minutes. Hour is added 1 and minute is set to 0
 {
minute = 0;
hour++;
 if (hour==24)
 {
  hour=0;
 }
 }
 }

 public String convert()  
 {//Converts to standard time with am and pm
String timer = null;
int counter = 0;

if (hour<12)
{
 if (hour<9)
   {
   if (minute>9)
   {
   timer = "0"+hour+":"+minute+" A.M.";
   }
   if (minute<10)
   {
     timer = "0"+hour+":0"+minute+" A.M";
   }
   }

 if (hour>9)
 {
   if (minute>9)
   {
   timer = ""+hour+":"+minute+" A.M.";
   }
   if (minute<10)
    {
     timer = ""+hour+":0"+minute+" A.M";
    }
  }
}

 if (hour ==12)
   {
   if (minute>9)
   {
   timer = ""+hour+":"+minute+" P.M.";
   }
   if (minute<10)
   {
     timer = ""+hour+":0"+minute+" P.M";
   }
 }



 if (hour>12)
 {
   hour-=12;
   if (hour ==12)
   {
   if (minute>9)
   {
   timer = ""+hour+":"+minute+" A.M.";
   }
   if (minute<10)
   {
     timer = ""+hour+":0"+minute+" A.M";
   }
 }

   if (hour<9)
   {
   if (minute>9)
   {
   timer = "0"+hour+":"+minute+" P.M.";
   }
   if (minute<10)
   {
     timer = "0"+hour+":0"+minute+" P.M";
   }
   }

 if (hour>9)
 {
   if (minute>9)
   {
   timer = ""+hour+":"+minute+" P.M.";
   }
   if (minute<10)
   {
     timer = ""+hour+":0"+minute+" P.M";
   }
 }

 }

return timer;
 }
```

And this is the code that is suppose to run:

```
 Time time7 = new Time(23,59);
 System.out.println("\ntime7: " + time7);
 System.out.println("convert time7: " + time7.convert());
 time7.addOne();
 System.out.println("increment time7: " + time7);
 System.out.println("convert time7: " + time7.convert());
```

I get the output as:

> time7: 2359
>
> convert time7: 11:59 P.M.
>
> increment time7: 1200
>
> convert time7: 12:00 P.M

But I need the output to be:

> time7: 2359
>
> convert time7: 11:59 P.M.
>
> increment time7: 0000
>
> convert time7: 12:00 A.M

All other parts to the program works just fine, until i get to `time7`.

Comment: Many of your if conditions are problem because your code enters multiple if conditions and overwrites the values set by previous if conditions. Either use switch-case or use if..else to make the paths exclusive.

Answer (score 3):

Starting with `hour` set to 23, then after this code:

```
if (hour>12)
{
    hour-=12;
    ...
```

what is the value of `hour`?

I'm afraid your code is needlessly complex, even if you fix the bug.  Look at the `String.format()` method for a much better way of formatting numbers for output that does not require you to handle all those "special cases" separately.

Comment: Time time7 = new Time(23,59); hour is 29 and minute is 59. It's user input. but  i have private int hour = 0;
  private int minute = 0; before the methods

Comment: @Hulu hour is 23 and minute 59.  You've got a typo.

Comment: didn't catch that, thanks.  Also how would i simplify my convert method?  I simplified my code to this after i had modulus division and a couple more if statements.

Answer (score 0):

After you increment and before you convert, you could add:

```
hour %= 24;
```

If hour is 24, it would then become 0.